# How to iterate through a Matrix without 2 for-loops

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, matrix

I have an exercize that demands an iteration through the elements of a matrix 'm', the difficulty is that the running time is supposed to be linear, meaning that if I use forloops, only one is allowed.

My Problem is now, that I always find myself wanting to use 2 forloops, but the running time wouldn't be linear, it would be quadratic. I was thinking about just iterating through m[i] and then checking if these are only the Int 0, but that would be 2 forloops again or maybe see if I could join the elements. Sadly, I couldn't find anything helpful already. I also thought about using the 'x in list' argument, but that wouldn't be helpful either.

Thanks in advance.

```py
m = [[0,0,0],
     [1,0,1],
     [1,0,0]]


#for i in m
#check all elements in m[i] for Ints '0'    

#m[0] --> All Elements are the Integer 0
#--> Output: True.
#The output should be a Boolean 'True', when the elements of one m[i] are all Integers 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep in mind that run-time analysis is based on the size of input. That is, if your input consists of n elements and you iterate over each element exactly once, this is `O(n)`. If your matrix is size `n x m`, then I believe linearity would be defined as `O(n x m)`, i.e. linear in the size of the input.

Also, the presence of a nested for loop does not necessarily mean that a program's runtime is quadratic, though this can be a helpful way to think about runtime.

EDIT: This doesn't change the theoretical runtime, but you can look into vectorized built-in functions (like `sum` in python) to handle each row altogether. As I said, this does not change the algorithmic runtime, but under-the-hood optimizations and vectorization can bring a speed up over a simple iteration over each matrix element.

As an elaboration to the "two for loops always means O(n^2)": this is only true in situations like:

```
# n elements in the input
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        # do things

# another possibility
# n elements in the input
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i):
        # worst case, i == j, bringing this to O(n^2)
        # do things
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I actually had the same thought, but my tutor said that we shouldn't use a nested forloop. We had a similar pseudo-code exercize, where we were supposed to analyse the run-time of a nested forloop. He said that we should only iterate once, meaning `O(n)` as our run-time and that two forloops always means `O(n^2)`. He was kind of picky about it. The matrix is a `n x n` adjacency matrix, where self-loops are not allowed.

Comment: Hmm he is incorrect about the statement "two for loops always means O(n^2)". The input size if somewhat a matter of perspective as well (i.e. if you say "my input is just the row length", then sure, iterating over the entire matrix is quadratic in the "size of input" which in this case is the row size). I'll edit my answer above to add another possibility.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the tip with the function sum()! I could iterate through the m[i] and then check if there is one sum(m[i]) == 0.

Comment: Yup, exactly! As I mentioned before (and this is what I meant by your tutor's statement not being correct), this does not reduce the algorithmic complexity, as the sum function itself must iterate over each of the elements in the row. However, it does lead to a real-world speed-up in Python due to vectorization and other under-the-hood optimizations! Feel free to select the answer if it helped you ;)